# Making click event in TS in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

Normally when adding a click event in Angular you would write this

```
<div (click)="myfunc()">click me </div>
```

but I want to do something like this in TS instead

```
`<div (click)="${this.myfunc()}">click me</div>`
```

It works a bit, but the click is made on load. 
Then I tried this

```
`<div (click)="() => ${this.myfunc}">click me</div>`
```

But that did not work at all. Any help ?

Here is how I call the modal, where I want to use the code

```
openModalWithComponent(img) {
    const initialState = {
      title: 'Modal with component',
      content: `
         <img src="${img}" />
         <div (click)="${this.onImageRemoveHandler()}">delete</div>`,
      header: false,
      footer: false
    };

    this.bsModalRef = this._modalService.show(
      ModalContentComponent, {initialState});
  }
```

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place ? Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: because I am calling a modal component, where I want to inject some code

Comment: And how is changing the syntax going to change how you call your modal ? We would need the framework used for the modal and the code of the function to help you. Otherwise, only the first solution would work.

Comment: I updated my description, so you can see the modal

Comment: But then again, I don't why you can't use the normal syntax ...

Comment: how ? Can you show what you mean ?

Comment: I mean you have to explain why you would use this syntax, this is a template litteral syntax and it's used for strings. So **again**, explain **the issue**, not *what you think is the solution*.

Comment: I want to call a method. The modal content is dynamic, therefore I want to inject my HTML into it using JavaScript.

Comment: Okay so you're trying to use JQuery with Angular, am I right ?

Comment: no. Where do you see any jquery ?

Comment: I don't see it, I'm trying to find out what the hell you're trying to do. I don't even remotely see what you are trying to achieve, simply call `openModalWithComponent()` and it will open your modal ...

Comment: Wait, are you talking about your modal content, `(click)="${this.onImageRemoveHandler()}"` ?

Comment: yes. That is exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: This will never work, Angular is processed into Javascript, once processed you lose any shorthand syntax like `(click)` or `{{ interpolation }}`. You can't (and shouldn't) append HTML to Angular elements, that's the very basics of Angular. Try [this google search](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Angular+innerHTML+click+event+not+working&rlz=1C1GCEU_frFR819FR820&oq=Angular+innerHTML+click+event+not+working&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.7048j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for instance, these are all the same issues as you.

Comment: so what would be a better solution, when the modal content is dynamic ?

Comment: Use dynamic components, stop using bootstrap, use the cdk ... The possibilities are endless, but adding html post-processing isn't one of them. Bootstrap should have documentation about that ...

Comment: I am using the Angular version of bootstrap.

Comment: Potato potato, it should have documentation too !